# Connection refused 10061 socket error on connect API

Tags: android, sockets

I have connected a mobile Android device to a PC and trying to make a communication with it via Socket communication over TCP.I use the connect API to make the connection. My PC here acts as a client and the Android device as a server.

The connect passes the very first time but it fails when I try to reconnect, the error is 10061 - connection refused actively by host.

```
if(connect((SOCKET)sock,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Error = %d",errno);
    return;
}
```

This happens intermittently so the point of firewall blocking the particular port is ruled out, Also I read in some forums that this may be a issue with limited backlog, however I increased the backlog in the listen call on the server to 100 but still this issue persists.

```
if(listen(socket,100) == -1)
{
 fprintf(stderr, "Error = %d",errno);
  return;
}
```

Could someone throw some light on this?
Note: This occurs on a particular set of PC's and in others this doesnt occur at all. Is it dependent on any hardware configuration?

Comment: I found the problem, its because of adb.exe. Whenever I try to reconnect I kill the existing adb.exe to connect to the socket again. But it so happens that the adb is not properly killed when I try to connect. So adding a few mili-seconds sleep after adb kill solved the issue.

Comment: Why are you killing ADB at all? If the Android device is connected to the same LAN as the PC, ADB is not even involved in the socket connection, the PC can connect to the device directly.  ADB is used for connecting a debugger to Android, hence its name "*A*ndroid *D*ebugger *B*ridge". It sounds more like your Android code is simply not calling `accept()` again after the first disconnect. That would account for the 10061 error.